# History of history

Tags: git, github

Is there a way in github to see the history of a branch's history?
What I mean is that a branch is obviously just a pointer to a commit hash. What I want is every time the hash being pointed to by the branch changes on the server, for that change to get logged somewhere, i.e. in gitorious every time someone pushes a branch there's a new entry added to the news feed, something like "username changed branchname from oldhash to newhash".

This is nice because git allows you to edit history via rebase, but if you can see the old hash you can still get back to the old history. I just can't find similar functionality in github. If you allow non-ff pushes, having a history of what hash a branch used to point to can be a real lifesaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this on GitHub itself, but your own local clone has it built-in - it's called the reflog. Take a look at `git help reflog` for more details (and [another link](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) for more info).

Comment: I'm aware of the reflog, but unfortunately it's not quite the same thing. For one thing it's far too verbose; it includes every change ever, so if I discover a week later that somehow master is screwed up because I did a rebase and thought I was in a different branch...what are the chances that I can reasonably figure out where it was supposed to be by looking through the reflog? The other problem of course is if someone else does that upstream, how can I find out who did it or when?

Comment: GitHub doesn't keep reflogs, so basically, you can't. (Be careful who you give write access to your repository.)

Comment: `git log --walk-reflogs <branchname>` can help for figuring out what the heck was going on.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. I'd hate to think that gitorious is superior to github in any way. ;)